# Прокси таймаут Java

Tags: http, java, proxy

Здравствуйте!

Использую следующую конструкцию для доступа к HTTP серверам:

```
URL url = new URL(sUrl);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyElement.getIP(),   proxyElement.getPort()));

HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);
```

Возникли вопросы:

1. Как прервать соединение по таймауту, иногда бывает, что прокси "подвисает" без ответа?
2. Как можно обойти указание точного типа прокси? Возможно ли это как-то определить до соединения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Более удобный способ реализовывать соединение через прокси - использование класса `ProxySelector`.

Он умеет нормально реагировать на тот случай, если прокси-сервер недоступен *(`failed` в имплементации)* и больше соответствует фабричной идеологии, которую стоит применять здесь.

Хороший пример по использованию - [Using ProxySelector to take control of what proxies to use and when](http://madhurtanwani.blogspot.com/2010/05/using-proxyselector-to-take-control-of.html).

Comment: Читал я про этот способ, но откуда он берет список прокси? Прокси-сервер может быть доступен, но быть очень медленным, мне это нужно обойти.

Comment: @Dex `ProxySelector` - это просто абстрактный класс, который расширяется самостоятельно. Т.е нужно отнаследоваться от него и реализовать методы `select` и `connectionFailed` *(см. пример).* Если хочется откинуть медленные прокси-серверы, можно либо раз в X секунд пинговать их внутри самого `ProxySelector`, либо пинговать их перед возвращением из метода `select`, и, соответственно либо отдавать как результат, либо пробовать другой.

Comment: @Dex Тут еще хорошо то, что вся логика выбора проксиков очевидно уходит внутрь класса, отнаследованного от `ProxySelector` и за пределами этого класса уже ни о чем беспокоиться не приходиться. Можно пойти еще дальше и, например, сделать реализации `OnlyFastProxySelector` и `AnyProxySelector`, которые, очевидно, будут возвращать только быстрые или любые проксики соответственно.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, он работает всегда, когда происходит обращение к сети?